# How much specialization should be done inside the class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm building PHP classes to do both specific and general tasks, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
class Cat
{
    public function cuddleNonStrayCat() {
        $this->washHands();
        $this->cuddleCat(); 
    }

    public function cuddleStrayCat() {
        $this->cuddleCat(); 
        $this->washHands();
        $this->getRabiesVaccine();
    }
    public function getRabiesVaccine() { ... }
    public function cuddleCat() { ... }
    public function washHands() { ... }
}

$cat = new Cat;

# Example 1 - Very compact to do a specialized thing:
$cat->cuddleStrayCat(); 

# Example 2 - Do the specialization outside of the class:
$cat->cuddleCat();  
$cat->washHands();
$cat->getRabiesVaccine();
```

First example I put the specialization (mess) inside the class, but keep it clean outside. Second example is the other way around.

Is one preferred over the other, or are there other and possibly better ways to do this?

Comment: Start by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q

Comment: Nice video. I need to watch it twice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does a "cat" contain the logic for cuddling a cat?

For some reason, you seem to think, that one should stuff as much logic inside one class as possible. That's wrong. A class should have one general purpose (that's basically the concept that [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) defines), but you have begun adding all the *loosely related* stuff in it - that's a recipe for creating a "god object", which contains every piece of your application's logic.

Look at it this way: why would cat be aware of how to wash hands of a human?